# airdroid app FileManager doesn't access to sdCard

Tags: sd-card, file-transfer, file-management, airdroid

AirDroid is a impressive app, but I'm not able to access from pc to th SD content, only to the internal folders (also named sd card I think)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: ¿?

The AirDroid app in the pc have an "Files" button in order to show an Explorer like File Manager, but the content is shown is the on in the "internal memory" of the device.
But the device have also an SD Card (16 GB in my case), these content can't be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

I've contact with other AirDroid user and this is an known bug for the developer, to be resolved in future version.

Answer (score 1):

[File Expert](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xcxin.filexpert&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsInhjeGluLmZpbGV4cGVydCJd) will give you both on-device, Explorer-like access to your files, and access over WiFi from your browser, an FTP client or Bluetooth.  You won't need a separate browser-access app.  It is well reviewed and free/no ads.

Comment: Thanks, I've installed the app, but some is going wrong, because I don't see the app in my device (Woxter Tablet).
I will try tomorrow.

Comment: Installed, and shared the content using browser, works BUT HAVE THE SAME PROBLEM OF AIRDRID:
- external sdcard is not available
- shows an sdcard but this is the internal one

The app itself have the same problem, the external sdcard are not visible.

The device have three storage as I can understand:<br> - internal memory, 1 GB - internal sdcard, 16 HB - external (removable) sdcard The problem is I can't access to the removable sdcard from the browser pc using airdroid app. Of course I can access to the external sdcard in my device.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with the "internal folders" are also named "sd card" seems weird to me.
Maybe you assume /sdcard is a local folder? Which it isn't that's the location of your SD card's content.

Above, when you want to access your SD card's content in your PC, it have to be dismounted from the phone which will make apps installed on it inaccessible. Mostly you have to approve the dismounting of the SD card manually from your phone. I can imagine that when AirDroid is installed on your SD card it cannot dismount it because it has some necessary files on it.

Comment: Maybe there is an conflict between those named "sd card".
The devide have three storage as I can understand:
- internal memory, 1 GB
- internal sdcard, 16 HB
- external (removable) sdcard

The problem is I can't access to the removable sdcard from the browser pc using airdroid app.
Of course I can access to the external sdcard in my device.